# gnome-terminal window doesn't refresh when maximized on ubuntu 22.04 (X11)

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal

Sometimes when I maximize the gnome-terminal window it stops refreshing. The content inside the terminal stops updating, while the terminal itself continues to work.

However, if I resize the window to a smaller size (by pressing the windows key and dragging the window), everything that was printed by the terminal during the time it was maximized shows up, and the terminal continues to work normally. If I maximize the window again, it again freezes.

Sometimes it can be fixed by repeatedly maximizing, resizing, maximizing, resizing, etc several times, until the maximized window finally works.

It also seems that the problem usually manifests after unlocking the machine, something like: maximized terminal window working -> lock screen -> unlock -> find maximized window "frozen".

Comment: Likely a bug with Wayland. I experience similar phenomena when using a browser full screen. It works at first, but at some point the screen is not anymore updated with the cursor movement.

Comment: I'm not using Wayland, I'm using X11.

Comment: Maybe the same as https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1471.

Comment: That would be relevant information to add to your question: use "edit"